# Printing dates (yyyy-mm format) across 4 month range with 2 month overlap

Tags: python, loops, date

Id like to work out a loop that can print the date, in yyyy-mm format, across 4 month increments, with a 2 month overlap. I can do this for one year, but Im struggling with how to extend it into the next year while adhering to the 4 month range and 2 month overlap.

The ideal outcome would be this...

2020-01,2020-02,2020-03,2020-04, 2020-03,2020-04,2020-05,2020-06, 2020-05,2020-06,2020-07,2020-08, 2020-07,2020-08,2020-09,2020-10, 2020-09,2020-10,2020-11,2020-12, 2020-11,2020-12,2021-01,2021-02, 2021-01,2020-2,2020-3,2020-04

Ive done the fallowing so far,

```
for j in range(20,22):
    for k in range(0,13,3):
        for l in range(1,7):
            while (k+l <=12)
                print('20'+str(j)+'-'+str(k+l))
                break
```

This works fine for a single year, but it doesn't extend into the next year that way Id like.

Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dateutil's [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) you can  add a month to a [date instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date). It's easier than using [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) because the length of a month depends on which month it is.

```
from collections import deque
from datetime import date
from itertools import count

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta  # pip install python-dateutil


def gen(start, n=4, overlap=2, limit=-1):
    month = relativedelta(months=1)
    initial = [start + i*month for i in range(n)]
    q = deque(initial, maxlen=n)
    for i in count():
        if i >= limit:
            break
        yield list(q)
        for _ in range(overlap):
            q.popleft()
            q.append(q[-1] + month)
```

```
>>> for chunk in gen(start=date(2020, 1, 1), limit=10):
...     print(", ".join([c.strftime("%Y-%m") for c in chunk]))
... 
2020-01, 2020-02, 2020-03, 2020-04
2020-03, 2020-04, 2020-05, 2020-06
2020-05, 2020-06, 2020-07, 2020-08
2020-07, 2020-08, 2020-09, 2020-10
2020-09, 2020-10, 2020-11, 2020-12
2020-11, 2020-12, 2021-01, 2021-02
2021-01, 2021-02, 2021-03, 2021-04
2021-03, 2021-04, 2021-05, 2021-06
2021-05, 2021-06, 2021-07, 2021-08
2021-07, 2021-08, 2021-09, 2021-10
```